# How to code the value from temperature sensor to the lcd in emu8086?

Tags: emu8086

I have the value from temperature sensor. How do I continue that coding to display the value from the temperature sensor to the LCD ?

```
ORG 2000H

DATA SEGMENT
    
; PORT ADDRESSES FOR LCD
 
PORTA1 EQU 00H
PORTB1 EQU 02H ; INPUT
PORTC1 EQU 04H ; UPPER LCD
CONTROL_REG1 EQU 06H ; LOWER LCD

;PORT ADDRESSES FOR ADC

PORTA2 EQU 10H ; INPUT TO DI
PORTB2 EQU 12H 
PORTC2 EQU 14H ; IN ADC
CONTROL_REG2 EQU 16H  

temperature_range db -10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 
           db 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39
           

humidity_range db 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,3,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59
               db 60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,7,71,72,73,74
               
;INITIALIZE THE 8255 FROM HUMIDITY SENSOR 

; TAKE TEMPERATURE FROM TEMPERATURE SENSOR

MOV AL, 02H
OUT PORTA2, AL

MOV AL, 06H
OUT CONTROL_REG2, AL

MOV AL, 00H
OUT CONTROL_REG2, AL

MOV AL,02H  
OUT CONTROL_REG2,AL

MOV AL,01H   
OUT CONTROL_REG2,AL

MOV AL,03H   
OUT CONTROL_REG2,AL

MOV AL,02H  
OUT CONTROL_REG2,AL 

MOV AL,00H  
OUT CONTROL_REG2,AL

IN AL, PORTC2
       
MOV AL, 10011010B
OUT CONTROL_REG2, AL

IN AL, PORTA2
```

Edit : added code some indentations to better explain what was said, better CTRL+C and CTRL+V and better intepretation.

Comment: Hy, you should avoid using [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) in your post

Comment: Question needs a bit of formatting